# Conditional distribution of joint normal when condition is an inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $(\varepsilon, \nu)$ be jointly normally distributed:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon \\ \nu \end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  , \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2 & \rho \sigma_{\varepsilon} \\ \rho \sigma_{\varepsilon} & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation between $\varepsilon$ and $\nu$. Then show that for any real constant $\alpha$:
$$\varepsilon \mid \nu > \alpha \sim N(\rho \sigma_{\varepsilon}\lambda(-\alpha), \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2(1-\rho^2))$$
where $\lambda(\cdot) = \frac{\phi(\cdot)}{\Phi(\cdot)}$, and $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the pdf and cdf of a standard normal distribution, respectively.

I know that the conditional distribution of $\varepsilon \mid \nu = \alpha$ is normally distributed with mean $\rho\sigma_{\varepsilon}\alpha$ and variance $\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2(1-\rho^2)$ by the properties of a joint normal distribution, but how do I prove the above when the condition is an inequality?

Comment: You need the conditional density of $\varepsilon \vert \nu > \alpha$. This is given by $$ \frac{1}{1-F_\nu (\alpha)} \int_{\alpha}^\infty f_{\varepsilon,\nu}(x,y) \,\mathrm d y. $$ Here, $f_{\varepsilon,\nu}$ is the joint density, and $F_\nu (\alpha)$ is the (marginal) CDF of $\nu$.

Comment: You could find the condition cdf $P(\varepsilon \le x\mid \nu > \alpha)$ and see if it can be written in terms of the standard normal cdf $\Phi$.

Comment: Since $P(\varepsilon \le x\mid \nu >\alpha)=\frac{P(\varepsilon \le x, \nu >\alpha)}{1-\Phi(\alpha)}$, one would have to evaluate $$\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x f_{\varepsilon,\nu}(\varepsilon,\nu)\,d\varepsilon\,d\nu$$ for the numerator. As per your result, the conditional cdf should evaluate to $\Phi\left(\frac{x-\cdot}{\cdot}\right)$.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699457/conditional-multivariate-normal-pdf-with-inequality-fx-1-x-2-a?rq=1.